# bash -- copying and change filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to copy all files from

> /dirA/[NAME].20151231.txt

to

> /dirB/20151231.[NAME].txt

and

> /dirC/20151231/[NAME].txt

i.e. I need to copy the files, but change the name.

You can assume that I know the "date" string before hand, so we can assume 20151231 is a supplied argument.

if I have a list of names, I can do something like

```
for n in $names; do; cp /dirA/$n.$date.txt /dirB/$date.$n.txt; done;
```

But what if I dont have a list of names? I am looking for an elegant solution as extracting them from dirA sounds a bit cumbersome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am just awful at asking questions. What I was looking for was a "`sed` for file names". And I found the answer -- that's `rename`.

Comment: Be aware that are several implementations of a `rename` utility. There is the standard (on LInux) provided by the `util-linux` package, and several other variants that are standalone utilities where the options differ considerably.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably reliable way of processing this material is:

```
date=20151231
cd /dirA || exit 1
mkdir -p "/dirC/$date" || exit 1
for file in *."$date.txt"
do
    name="${file%.$date.txt}"
    cp "$file" "/dirB/$date.$name.txt"
    cp "$file" "/dirC/$date/$name.txt"
done
```

The `cd` operation is checked; if it fails, there is no point in continuing.  Likewise, the `mkdir -p` operation ensures that the dated directory under `/dirC` exists or exits.  The relevant error messages were already generated by `cd` and `mkdir`.

Using the shell globbing to generate the file names is best; it avoids issues with 'what happens if the file name contains spaces (or newlines, or other unexpected characters)'.
The assignment extracts the '[NAME]' portion of the file name.  This is then used to copy the file from `/dirA` to the relevant locations under `/dirB` and `/dirC`.  It would be feasible to check that `/dirB` and `/dirC` also exist if you thought that was necessary.